# Critical point from ab initio calculations

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-chemistry, ab-initio

I was wondering if it is possible to calculate the critical point (*e.g.*, temperature, pressure, and density) other than via experiments or equations of state like *ab initio* calculations.

Would anyone with more experience have any ideas?

Comment: It's more like estimation than calculation, I think, but check here for example: https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2020GL089599

Comment: Are you asking for answer "in principle" or "in practice". Given enough computational resource and computing time, any properties of a chemical system can be calculated using ab initio calculation. In practice? I'm not sure. But @Mithoron provide a pretty good resource.